# убрать подсказку google chrome

Tags: php, javascript

можно ли как то сделать чтобы на моем сайте при клике на какой то текст в гугл хроме (Андроид) не вылазила подсказка найти определение слова в интернете?

Comment: Это невозможно.

Comment: @Yuri, нет ничего невозможного. Всего-то нужно отреверсить приложение хрома, прокинуть интерфейс управления в JS, раздобыть валидный сертификат гугла, подписать приложение, установить его и всё. Возможно же :)

Comment: @Other, легче Пентагон взломать :D

Comment: @Yuri, забавно, сложно будет взломать то, чего нет. Есть много автономных кусочков сетей под одним названием.